# Working with weekdays in number format in R lubriday::wday

Tags: r, lubridate

Greetings lovely people of SO, I am currently working with a dataset that has columns for weekdays  in a number format, for weekdays the number one represents Monday and 7 Sunday, preliminary I am trying to make use of some sort of library that can convert this numbers into string/text format for example if I were to pass the vector `days` I would like to get the number days as text form.

Input:

```
days<-c(1,3,5,7)
```

Desired output:

```
"monday", "wednesday", "friday", "sunday"
```

I am using the library `lubridate` in R when running this line of code I get:

```
> wday(days,  week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1), label = TRUE)
[1] Sun Tue Thu Sat
Levels: Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat < Sun
```

Which is not what I want since number 1 must be Mon and 7 Sun and even if I try to change the parameter `week_sart` to any number, I still get Sun instead of Mon and thus all other days are incorrect.

```
> wday(days,  week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 7), label = TRUE)
[1] Sun Tue Thu Sat
Levels: Sun < Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat
```

So I ended up running this line to get my desired output:

```
wday(days+1,  week_start = getOption("lubridate.week.start", 1), label = TRUE)
[1] Mon Wed Fri Sun
Levels: Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat < Sun
```

But what I really want to to have a function that will set one as mon by default in case I have to work in other machines , does someone knows how to properly change the parameters of the  `lubridate::wday` function to get my desired output? Thank you so much guys.

Comment: I'd also point out that the idea of `getOption()` is to get an option that's been previously set. If you want to use a custom value for a single run of a function you don't need to use `getOption`, you can simply say `wday(days, week_start = 7, label = TRUE)`

Comment: Though I'll amend my first comment - despite not being documented [there is a `wday` method for numeric input](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/9cece5680d0280c5cd1ccdbc9309ccb4724b3a34/R/accessors-day.r#L73)

Comment: I believe the behavior you were seeing is a bug in lubridate, I've submitted [an issue here](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/1025).

Comment: Thank you so much sir I have looked into it you are a rock star! @GregorThomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this efficiently without `lubridate`, using `days` as an index vector.

```r
w <- tolower(weekdays(.Date(4:10)))
w
## [1] "monday"    "tuesday"   "wednesday" "thursday"  "friday"    "saturday"  "sunday"

w[days]
## [1] "monday"    "wednesday" "friday"    "sunday"
```

If you want a factor, then you can do

```r
gl(7L, 1L, labels = w)[days]
## [1] monday    wednesday friday    sunday   
## Levels: monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
```

optionally passing `ordered = TRUE` to `gl`.

It's worth mentioning that the `weekdays` result is locale-dependent. Non-English locales will use non-English names for week days, etc. If you want completely reproducible results, then construct `w` yourself.

```r
w <- c("monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday")
```